# Discord JS Message Leveling System

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a level system for my discord bot, I want it so if I reach level 5, it will give me a role. I want it to be so when you reach a certain level you will be given a role.

I pasted the code for the message leveling system I am using.

```js
bot.on("message", async message => {
    let xpAdd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 8;

    if(!xp[message.author.id]) {
        xp[message.author.id] = {
            xp: 0,
            level: 1
        }
    }
    if(xp[message.author.id].level[5]) //idk if im doing this right, I want it so if level reaches a certain number, it will give out a role
    {
        console.log("skrt");
    }
    let curxp = xp[message.author.id].xp;
    let curlvl = xp[message.author.id].level;
    let nxtlvl = xp[message.author.id].level * 300;
    let rankuplvl = xp[message.author.id].xp * 7;
    xp[message.author.id].xp = curxp + xpAdd;

    if(nxtlvl <= xp[message.author.id].xp) {
        xp[message.author.id].level = curlvl + 1;

        const lvlUp = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("You leveled up!")
            .setColor("#FFC0CB")
            .addField("NEW LEVEL", curlvl + 1);

        message.channel.send(lvlUp);
    }
    fs.writeFile("./xp.json", JSON.stringify(xp), (err) => {
        if(err) console.log(error)
    });

    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "level")) {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
        if(!xp[message.author.id]){
            xp[message.author.id] = {
                xp: 0,
                level: 1
            };
        }
    let curxp = xp[message.author.id].xp;
    let curlvl = xp[message.author.id].level;
    let nxtlvl = curlvl * 300;
    let difference = nxtlvl - curxp;

    const lvlEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username)
        .setColor("#FFC0CB")
        .addField("XP", curxp, true)
        .addField("Level", curlvl, true)
        .setFooter(`${difference} XP  until next rank!`, message.author.displayAvatarURL);
    message.channel.send(lvlEmbed)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down what we need to do in order to reach your desired behavior. Assuming you're using the stable branch (most likely)...

1. Check if the user's level is 5.
   *[Equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators)*
2. Retrieve the desired role.
   *[`Guild.roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles)*

   - By ID: *[`Map.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) or use the ID as the [RoleResolvable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleResolvable) in #3.*
   - By property: *[`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find)*
3. Add a role to the user.
   *[`GuildMember.addRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole)*

Now, let's put it all together and implement it into your code.

```js
if(nxtlvl <= xp[message.author.id].xp) {
  xp[message.author.id].level = curlvl + 1;

  // Check if the user's level is 5.
  if (xp[message.author.id].level === 5) {
    // Retrieve the desired role. Uncomment whichever line you need, as described.
    // const role = message.guild.roles.get('idHere');
    // const role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Level 5');

    message.member.addRole(role) // Or simply use the role ID directly.
      .catch(console.error);     // Make sure to catch any rejected promises.
  }

  // Continue with your level-up embed.
}
```

Comment: It works like it needs to be, thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) using the checkmark to the left if it effectively solves your problem.